# Parameterized logging in slf4j - how does it compare to scala's by-name parameters?

Tags: scala, parameter-passing, slf4j, callbyname

Here are two statements that seem to be generally accepted, but that I can't really get over:

1) Scala's by-name params gracefully replace the ever-so-annoying log4j usage pattern:

```
if (l.isDebugEnabled() ) { 
      logger.debug("expensive string representation, eg: godObject.toString()") 
   }
```

because the by-name-parameter (a **Scala-specific language feature**) doesn't get evaluated before the method invocation.

2) However, this problem is solved by parametrized logging in slf4f:

```
logger.debug("expensive string representation, eg {}:", godObject[.toString()]);
```

So, how does this work? 
Is there some low-level magic involved in the slf4j library that prevents the evaluation of the parameter before the "debug" method execution? (is that even possible? Can a *library* impact such a fundamental aspect of the language?)

Or is it just the simple fact that an object is passed to the method -  rather than a String? (and maybe the toString() of that object is invoked in the debug( ) method itself, if applicable).

But then, isn't that true for log4j as well? (it does have methods with Object params).
And wouldn't this mean that if you pass a string - as in the code above - it would behave identically to log4j?

I'd really love to have some light shed on this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no magic in slf4j. The problem with logging used to be that if you wanted to log let's say

```
logger.debug("expensive string representation: " + godObject)
```

then no matter if the debug level was enabled in the logger or not, you always evaluated `godObject.toString()`which can be an expensive operation, and then also string concatenation. This comes simply from the fact that in Java (and most languages) arguments are evaluated before they're passed to a function.

That's why slf4j introduced `logger.debug(String msg, Object arg)` (and other variants for more arguments). The whole idea is that you pass cheap arguments to the `debug` function and it calls `toString` on them and combines them into a message only if the debug level is on.

Note that by calling

```
logger.debug("expensive string representation, eg: {}", godObject.toString());
```

you drastically reduce this advantage, as this way you convert `godObject` all the time, before you pass it to `debug`, no matter what debug level is on. You should use only

```
logger.debug("expensive string representation, eg: {}", godObject);
```

---

However, this still isn't ideal. It only spares calling `toString` and string concatenation. But if your logging message requires some other expensive processing to create the message, it won't help. Like if you need to call some `expensiveMethod` to create the message:

```
logger.debug("expensive method, eg: {}",
    godObject.expensiveMethod());
```

then `expensiveMethod` is always evaluated before being passed to `logger`. To make this work efficiently with slf4j, you still have to resort back to

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    logger.debug("expensive method, eg: {}",
        godObject.expensiveMethod());
```

Scala's call-by-name helps a lot in this matter, because it allows you to wrap arbitrary piece of code into a function object and evaluate that code only when needed. This is exactly what we need. Let's have a look at  [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s), for example. This library exposes methods like

```scala
def debug(msg: => String) { ... }
```

Why no arguments like in slf4j's `Logger`? Because we don't need them any more. We can write just

```scala
logger.debug("expensive representation, eg: " +
    godObject.expensiveMethod())
```

We don't pass a message and its arguments, we pass directly a piece of code that is evaluated to the message. But only if the logger decides to do so. If the debug level isn't on, nothing that's within `logger.debug(...)` is ever evaluated, the whole thing is just skipped. Neither `expensiveMethod` is called nor any `toString` calls or string concatenation happen. So this approach is most general and most flexible. You can pass any expression that evaluates to a `String` to `debug`, no matter how complex it is.

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you very much. I guess your thorough explanation makes up for the magic I was hoping for and didn't get. :)